# If radio button is selected, show element in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to get a radio button to display an element when the radio button is selected. I've tried multiple different solutions. [(ngModel)] would throw up errors.

I can't seem to get the value of the radio to pass through the ngIf and no matter how much I try I can't seem to get a "true" statement out to pass through the ngIf either.

Here is my .ts for the form:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
import { MdRadioChange } from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'activation-role',
  template: `
    <div class="form-group" [formGroup]="group" >
      <mat-radio-group formControlName="role" [attr.data-optional]="canViewDiv">
        <mat-radio-button #{{role.id}} (change)="onRadioChange($event)" class="radio-button-vertical" *ngFor="let role of activation_roles" [value]="role.id">
          <div>{{role.label}}</div> 
          <mat-hint>{{role.additionalText}}</mat-hint>
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </div>`

})

export class ActivationRoleComponent {

  @Input() group: FormGroup;

  canViewDiv: boolean = true;

  onRadioChange(event: MdRadioChange) {

    if (event.value === 'option1') {
      this.canViewDiv = true;

      console.log(event.value);
      console.log(this.canViewDiv);
    } else {
      this.canViewDiv = false;

      console.log(event.value);
      console.log(this.canViewDiv);
    }
  }


  private activation_roles = [{
    id: 'option1',
    value: 'Option one',
    label: 'Option one',
    status: true,
    additionalText: 'This is additional text'
  },{
    id: 'option2',
    value: 'Option two',
    label: 'Option two',
    status: false,
    additionalText: 'This is additional text two'
  },{
    id: 'option3',
    value: 'Option three',
    label: 'Option three',
    status: false,
    additionalText: 'This is additional text three'
  }];

}export class ActivationRoleComponent {

  @Input() group: FormGroup;

  canViewDiv: boolean = true;

  onRadioChange(event: MdRadioChange) {

    if (event.value === 'option1') {
      this.canViewDiv = true;

      console.log(event.value);
      console.log(this.canViewDiv);
    } else {
      this.canViewDiv = false;

      console.log(event.value);
      console.log(this.canViewDiv);
    }
  }


  private activation_roles = [{
    id: 'option1',
    value: 'Option one',
    label: 'Option one',
    status: true,
    additionalText: 'This is additional text'
  },{
    id: 'option2',
    value: 'Option two',
    label: 'Option two',
    status: false,
    additionalText: 'This is additional text two'
  },{
    id: 'option3',
    value: 'Option three',
    label: 'Option three',
    status: false,
    additionalText: 'This is additional text three'
  }];

}
```

And here is my form html:

```
<mat-accordion>
        <!-- ROLE ACCORDION -->
        <mat-expansion-panel class="activation-form__role" expanded="true" #roleAccordion>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header #roleAccordionHeader>Your Role</mat-expansion-panel-header>

          <activation-role [group]="roleGroup"></activation-role>

          <mat-action-row>
            <button mat-button color="primary" class="activation-form__role__next-btn" (click)="expandStep(1)" [disabled]="roleGroup.invalid" >Next</button>
          </mat-action-row>
        </mat-expansion-panel>

        <mat-expansion-panel *ngIf="roleGroup?.data-optional === 'true'" class="rmb-form__corporate-details" #strataManagerDetailsAccordion [disabled]="detailsGroup.invalid">
        </mat-expansion-panel>
<mat-accordion>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have created a simple which implements what you want to achieve here; https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxdbgi-rmc2vz
What error you receive while using ngModel?

Comment: Hey thanks, i'm getting "ngmodel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive" when I use ngmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your approach. First thing is, you are trying to use a boolean value which is inside a child component i.e. activation-role in your parent component i.e. form component. You need to emit the value from the child component to parent after it changes then show and hide the div in your parent component based on that value.

Also, in activation-role, you dont need to use form group of parent component by passing as an input because the form inside this component only has a radio button. You can achieve what you want without using form group inside the activation-route component and using ngModel.

I have created a stackblitz solution for you in which i have implemented activation-role component similar to your component. I didn't know about the form component so i have created my own custom form and used it in activation-role and based on the radio buttons in the activatation-role component, a mat-expnasion-panel is hidden or shown.
Here is the link to the solution: [Show hide div based on radio](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxdbgi-fwkzhf) .
In this solution, i am emitting the value of radio button from child component and using it in parent component. Try to understand what is being done in the solution so you can get better understanding of input and output in angular.
For more on input output, see [Input Output in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

**Update for @Gaurang Sondagar**
I have modified the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxdbgi-qfjnqs) according to your requirements. It contains 2 components, `form-component` and `expansion-panel`. The expansion panel contains contains the panel and the radio group.

In `form-component` there is `allRadioPanels` array, using which the panels are rendered. Each object of this array contains binded `SelectedValue` for radio button of each panel, binded `Comments` value for each panel and `CommentsRequiredValue` to tell which selected option means that comments are required for that panel.

On the bottom there is submit button which becomes disbaled if for any panel, the `CommentsRequiredValue` if equal to `SelectedValue` and `Comments` are blank.

For example, for Panel 2, the `CommentsRequiredValue` is `Option 2` and the `SelectedValue` is initially set to `Option 2` as well. The initially disabled submit button will enable if you change the value of Panel 2 radio from Option 2 or enter comments in it.

Will work similarly for all panels.

Comment: Hey Nabil, I followed this step by step and it worked! Thank you so much, i've been moving over to Angular 5 and this was a sticking point in my form build.

This is the accepted answer, saved me a ton of head scratching and your explanation was clear.

Thank you so much again.

Comment: Hello, I am facing the issue because i am having multiple radio button group in ngFor loop and i want to append or modify an element in a specific panel on radio button change event. You are having only one radio button group and i am having multiple radio button group so can you please tell me how can i do this, thanks in advance!

Comment: @GaurangSondagar please see the update in my answer.

Comment: Hello Nabil, Thank you for your replay but actually my issue is different, see, I am having 20 mat-expansion-panel and each expansion-panel having one radio group and each radio group having 5 radio buttons, and below radio button there is one comment box. So i want something like when i select third radio button  then specific this expansion-panel comment box will optional otherwise it's required. Currently change happening in all mat-expansion-panel so want do changes on specific panel that i have select radio button. So can you please provide me example something like it. thanks in advance.

Comment: @NabilShahid  Please reply to my above things and if I impress with your answer then I will hire you for my next angular project.

Comment: @NabilShahid your above stackblitz link is not working properly so can you please check it.

Comment: @GaurangSondagar it is working for me. I have forked another: Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxdbgi-prahk2?file=main.ts   try this. Enter comments in panel 2 and the button will enable.

Comment: @NabilShahid your above example is very good, but can you please change this example like if i select the second radio button then that panel comment box is optional otherwise required and submit button should work like this validation.

Comment: Here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxdbgi-prahk2 .Replaced `CommentsRequiredValue` string with `CommentsRequiredValues` array of strings in which you can specify all values of a radio buttons for which comments are required.

Comment: @GaurangSondagar see comment above

Comment: @NabilShahid, your answer is good but when i select the first option from all five panels then submit button is disabled and form is invalid even comment option is optional when i select the first option so please check it.

Comment: @GaurangSondagar second option means optional comments. The solution is correct. Please look at `CommentsRequiredValues` in form component for each panel to see which options means required comments for each panel. If you want to change any the options for which comments are required, you need to change this array accordingly for each panel.

Comment: Please see  this link actually i am facing this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56730314/input-box-attribute-set-dynamically-on-radio-button-change

Comment: Thanks, @NabilShahid Finally I have got a solution from you.

Comment: @GaurangSondagar No problem. Happy to help...!

Comment: @NabilShahid can you please send me your skpe id? For we will connect in future

Comment: @GaurangSondagar you can email me or message me on hangouts: nabil110176@gmail.com